# Known RVM versions not very recent?

Tags: ruby, rvm

Presently on OS X 10.6.8 if I run

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
rvm get stable
```

The highest Ruby is `[ruby-]1.9.3-head`.

Running `rvm get stable` does not change this. If I want to install Ruby 2.2 RVM says `Version '2.2.2' is to confusing to select ruby interpreter.`

Do I have to download the latest (2.2.3) manually and install? Will this not gum up RVM?

Comment: You don't say what version of RVM are you running, which is kinda important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of RVM you're running but RVM is plenty capable of handling the problem. From [the documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading):

> Is `rvm get stable` not working? Is `rvm get latest` telling you **You already have the latest version!** , but you know you don't? Try this:
>
> ```
>     $ rvm get head
>     $ rvm reload
>     $ rvm get stable
> ```
>
> If that does not work for you, you can always use the installer to update:
>
> ```
>     $ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
>     $ rvm reload
> ```

Reloading RVM itself won't affect any previously installed Rubies or gems; In other words it's safe.

Comment: That led to the fix.  Calling the installer generated `GPG signature verification failed for [...]`.  Following the suggestion of downloading the signatures solved the issue.

Comment: (Braincramp for not having verified version, which was rather old.)